# Is attempt like this, when using Application class, breaking MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my application I am using two view models. **MainViewModel** if fiered when **MianWindow** is initialized. And **UpdateViewModel** is fiered when **UpdateWindow** is initialized.

The **update VM** is supposed to use data from collection that is a property of the **main VM** and has its instance aready, and I need to refer to it somehow. And I was wondering, is refering to this collection with `MainViewModel vm = (MainViewModel)win.DataContext;` is breaking MVVM pattern or testability somehow or is any kind of antipattern? Or maybe the collections has to be passed **update VM** as a parameters, and sent back? Thank you.

The code:

```
public class UpdateViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public UpdateViewModel()
        {
            Jockeys = new ObservableCollection<LoadedJockey>();

            PopulateCollections();
        }

        private void PopulateCollections()
        {
            MainWindow win = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
            MainViewModel vm = (MainViewModel)win.DataContext;

            Jockeys = vm.Jockeys; //is it ok?

            vm.Jockeys //is it ok?
        }

        public ObservableCollection<LoadedJockey> Jockeys { get; private set; }

    }
```

Comment: We need more context than this. What are `MainWindow` and `MainViewModel`? How does you `xaml` look like? What is this code doing at all? Is this a new window, a popup, a user-control, etc, etc... Currently, this is too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainWindow` is a view object which should be avoided in `ViewModel` classes. Passing the collection as constructor parameter to the `UpdateViewModel` would be better. If you want to achieve a high level of testability, you would need to study more about dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was suspecting, that it could be too tight coupling. Right now I started to learn about ViewModel navigation.